# How to stop Yii's LESS from making my application slow?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I got this:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\APP\www\protected\extensions\less\lib\lessphp\lessc.inc.php on line 504
```

I think it might have to do with this:

```
'components'=>array(
  'less'=>array(
    'class'=>'ext.less.components.LessCompiler',
    'forceCompile'=>true, // indicates whether to force compiling
    //'compress'=>false, // indicates whether to compress compiled CSS
    //'debug'=>false, // indicates whether to enable compiler debugging mode
    'paths'=>array(
      'less/style.less'=>'css/style.css',
    ),
  ),
```

1. Does forceCompile mean the css files gets regenerated every time?
2. Would this slow down my application?
3. If I don't force compile, will it be faster?
4. Is there anything else I can do to speed up my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by this settings:

```
    'components'=>array(
    'less'=>array(
    'class'=>'ext.less.components.LessCompiler',
    'forceCompile'=>YII_DEBUG, // indicates whether to force compiling
    //'compress'=>false, // indicates whether to compress compiled CSS
    //'debug'=>false, // indicates whether to enable compiler debugging mode
    'paths'=>array(
      'less/style.less'=>'css/style.css',
    ),
   ),
```

Change your forceCompile = YII_DEBUG. IN DEBUG Mode Set 'forceCompile'=>true. When you work on Debug increase the PHP MAX Execution time

Comment: So to answer my question, my app will be much faster with this enabled and there's likely nothing else causing it to be slow?